# t-sql changing '=' to '> or <' in a case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is part of a big query.

What I'm trying to do is, if the variable `@exemptionStartDate = '1900-01-01'`, then just select everything,

ie. `ce.ExemptionStartDate = ce.ExemptionStartDate`.

Otherwise, I only want rows where `ce.ExemptionStartDate > @exemptionStartDate`

ce.ExemptionStartDate is of DateTime value

```
SELECT foobar 
WHERE foo = bar
AND ce.ExemptionStartDate = CASE WHEN @exemptionStartDate = '1900-01-01' THEN ce.ExemptionStartDate ELSE (> @exemptionStartDate) END
```

is it possible?  Or will I have to do the hacky thing of making everything a long string, and just adding onto it as necessary?

I'm getting a syntax error, and don't know how to form such a thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not need to complicate matters

```
if @exemptionStartDate = '1900-01-01'
set @exemptionStartDate = '1753-01-01' --lowest date for datetime
```

and then it is just

```
where ce.ExemptionStartDate > @exemptionStartDate
```

Comment: Wow, silly me, thanks lol.  The simplest answers are the best!  I was also looking for a solution to the case statement though, since I use it often, and sometimes run into that situation where I end up making everything red text...

Answer (score 2):

<strike>You need to include the column in the cases</strike>:
**Update** This query will work:

```
AND (@exemptionStartDate = '1900-01-01'
     OR ce.ExemptionStartDate > @exemptionStartDate)
```

See cyberwiki's answer on how to use `CASE`

Comment: SQL Server does not allow `standing boolean expressions`. Try this: `SELECT CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN 1=2 ELSE 1=3 END` => error. The CASE statement must return something, and (true) boolean is not a valid datatype.

Comment: @richard-aka-cyberkiwi Thanks for pointing that out. (it is valid in MySql though)

Answer (score 2):

Would it be save to assume that all of your ExemptionStartDate values in the table are greater than 1900-01-01?

If so, you could simplify to:

```
...
WHERE foo = bar
AND ce.ExemptionStartDate > @exemptionStartDate
```

Comment: @Richard: So would the OP's `ce.ExemptionStartDate = ce.ExemptionStartDate`, so it seemed reasonable to assume the column does not contain null values.

Comment: Reasonable, although I think the OP is after "optional filtering" for which the general technique is to use `@var is null` or `@var = {marker}` to short-circuit the evaluation, instead of having to inspect the index range.

Comment: @Richard a valid point re: checking for null but I believe the execution plan generator will re-arrange automatically to short-circuit if possible.

Comment: @Richard: As pointed out [here](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/), that technique (`@var is null or @var = {marker}`) is usually not a very good one.

Comment: @Basic `datetime >= 0` actually needs to consult the index, because datetime can go to -ve values.

Comment: @Richard - Sorry, I thought you were referring to needing to have the NULL check before the date comparison eg `@var is null or @var = {marker}` as opposed to `@var = {marker} or @var is null`

Comment: @Joe read this (both links from the redirector). It's better http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html  It can work better

Comment: Wow you two got really technical lol.  Thanks for the feedback, I'll read the article you posted thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

Your query should really be

```
SELECT foobar 
WHERE foo = bar
AND (@exemptionStartDate = 0 OR ce.ExemptionStartDate > @exemptionStartDate)
```

If you did want a CASE statement, here's a logic trick

```
SELECT foobar 
WHERE foo = bar
AND ce.ExemptionStartDate >
    CASE
    WHEN @exemptionStartDate = 0 THEN ce.ExemptionStartDate-1
    ELSE ce.ExemptionStartDate
    END
```

It looks neat, but it won't do your query any favours with indexes.  Stick to the top one.  The difference between the first and 2nd is that the 2nd will NOT show any `null` ce.ExemptionStartDate records.

Comment: Interesting.  Do you mind explaining how both work (confused with the 0)?  And why are you using zero (0)?  Or is that just for example?

Comment: @Fritos - select convert(datetime, 0) => '1900-01-01'. It is the numeric equivalent, since datetime values are parsed into some numeric representation anyway.